# Dynamic numbers of fields depending on values of another field on Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

i want to create the form with field `room`, it is integer field. depending on value of this field, should be created same number of another fields `adult` and `children` and depending of fields `children`, should be created same numbers of fields `children_age`. But when i leave `children` field empty it rise "All fields required"
forms.py

```
class RoomsForm(forms.Form):
        rooms = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)

class TouristsForm(forms.Form):
        adult = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Adults'), min_value=1, initial=1, widget = forms.HiddenInput)
        children = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Children'), min_value=1, required=False, widget = forms.HiddenInput)

class ChildrenAgeForm(forms.Form):
        children_age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=2, max_value=10, required=False, widget = forms.HiddenInput)
```

views.py

```
def RoomsForm(request):
        TouristsFormSet = formset_factory(TouristsForm)
        ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm)
        if request.method == 'POST':
                rooms_form = RoomsForm(request.POST, prefix='rooms_form')
                tourists_formset = TouristsFormSet(request.POST, prefix='tourists')
                childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(request.POST, prefix='childrenage')
                if rooms_form.is_valid() and tourists_formset.is_valid() and childrenage_formset.is_valid():
                        rooms = rooms_form.cleaned_data['rooms']

                        for i in range(0, tourists_formset.total_form_count()):
                                tourists_form = tourists_formset.forms[i]
                                print tourists_form.cleaned_data
```

I don't know why it happens. Maybe I choose wrong way to realize it. Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Perhaps a possible problem is that you are using room_form even though it may not be valid. Please note when you have a conditional like: a and b or c, it gets interpreted as (a and b) or c. This means False and False or True will be True.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was mistake. The problem happens when I use `and`